# Elevate user-permissions in Unity so I can move folders

Tags: permissions

I'm switching from Windows 7 so please excuse my newbie question.

Is it possible to elevate privileges of local user so it can access entire file system from Unity UI (even if it's very very bad thing to do:) ?

For example I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA tar. I unpacked it to **~/temp**_idea and want to move it to **/opt**. But I can't. As soon as I try moving it in the UI I get "**Permission denied**" error.

I can do it in terminal via `sudo mv` of course but it would be very nice to be able to do it in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gksu nautilus` command in the Unity dash prompt ( Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> ). This will open the Nautilus file browser and then you can do the copy, move, delete stuff using UI.

#### ***Be warned! Using nautilus with root privilege is very bad and you can do much harm to your PC with it, of course unintentionally.***